# docker login gives bogus "Success" response?

Tags: docker

**Version**

```
[root@pecan-9A firstDocker]# docker-latest --version
Docker version 1.13.1, build 6774275/1.13.1
```

**Bogus response for `docker login`?**

I used a (very likely) non-existing account, or I used a valid account
but with a deliberately wrong password.  In both instances, 
the response was `Login Succeeded`.  But then my following command
(`docker-latest push`) would failed with `Index response didn't contain any endpoints`

```
[root@pecan-9A firstDocker]# docker-latest login hub.docker.com
Username (leeyuiwah): bogus (I don't think this is a valid account)
Password:                   (just type in some junk)
Login Succeeded

[root@pecan-9A firstDocker]# docker-latest login hub.docker.com
Username: leeyuiwah         (valid account)
Password:                   (type in a bogus password)
Login Succeeded
```

**Next command would fail**

```
[root@pecan-9A firstDocker]# docker-latest  tag friendlyhello hub.docker.com/leeyuiwah/get-started:part2
[root@pecan-9A firstDocker]# docker-latest push hub.docker.com/leeyuiwah/get-started:part2
The push refers to a repository [hub.docker.com/leeyuiwah/get-started]
3088bc0df692: Preparing
fa9c71108753: Preparing
4cc654f2b860: Preparing
24b02a08f57d: Preparing
aed9311ebf15: Preparing
17f9d9d4ce37: Waiting
18f9b4e2e1bc: Waiting
Index response didn't contain any endpoints
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend trying to upgrade first, 1.13 is a 9 month old release. This may also be caused by an http proxy on your network.

```
$ docker login 
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username (*****): 
Password: 
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password

$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:40:46 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:39:27 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```